# how to run "for" loop in python to obtain a finite result

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a alphabet fibonnaci series which has an output like:

```
A, AB, AAB, ABAAB...
```

I thought of running a for-loop, which iterates through a list and appends the list with the elements which are sum of previous strings.

The code which I wrote for it is

```
series=["A","AB"]

for i in series:
    series.append("i-1"+"i")


print(series)
```

But every time I run this code the compiler hangs. I tried online IDEs too. No result. Just a blank response.

Comment: You add an item to list, then loop, add, loop, add... infinite.

Comment: Move the print statement inside the for loop to get an output once a new value is computed. As noted above, your for loop never terminates.

Answer (score 1):

Try using generator functions.

e.g.

```py
def infinite_loop():
    prev = ['A', 'AB']
    while True:
        yield prev[0], prev[1]
        prev = prev[1], prev[0]+prev[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not too worried about your memory (storing values in 'series' list will quickly be very memory consuming), you can use this simple trick:

```
SERIES = ["A", "AB"]
def get_element(i): # use this function to get element from SERIES list
    while len(SERIES) <= i:
        SERIES.append(SERIES[-2] + SERIES[-1])
    return SERIES[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

> But every time I run this code the compiler hangs

```
for i in series:
    series.append("i-1"+"i")
```

I assume you mean "the runtime hangs" - but anyway: the reason is pretty obvious - you iterate over a list, and at each iteration you add an element to it, so there's always one more element to iterate over... To visualize what happens, just add a couple print() in the loop:

```
for i in series:
    print("before: {}".format(series))
    series.append("i-1"+"i")
    print("after: {}".format(series))
```